# How to access user-defined functions of a servlet?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I tried searching about this, but didnt got a solid answer. Is it possible to call functions other than doGet or doPost of a servlet from a JSP. I know you can call them indirectly by making a call to either doGet or doPost and then calling the function from there.

For eg:

```
public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    }

    public void myFunc(){
    }
```

How to call myFunc from my JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The published interface for Servlets is only the `doXXX` methods (doGet, doPost, etc). You are right that the only way to invoke other methods is by calling the published interface and then calling the other methods.